# Recompyling python complyled .exe to execute on linux

Tags: python, linux, py2exe, uncompyle6

I have a program, compyled from python sources for windows. But i need to execute it on linux server.

My plan was in decompyling it by https://github.com/LookiMan/EXE2PY-Decompiler, but it doesn't give any positive result cause code is encrypted. I don't need to edit sources, so can i just recompyle it to linux executable?

Comment: Why would you try to go to an executable at all? The easier target is just trying to get .pyc files (which are basically already there bundled in the executable, with the lone caveat that some headers are stripped off).

Comment: CPython is an interpreted language -- it's "compiled" only to a (version-specific) bytecode. When you make an exe with freeze / cx_freeze / pyinstaller / etc, those "exe files" are just copying the whole Python interpreter and your bytecode into an archive with a wrapper that unpacks them into a temporary directory and runs them; that's extra work that makes it slower to run than it would just be if you didn't bother trying to make an executable at all.

Comment: Anyhow -- what your options are depends on exactly which version of Python the original program was compiled; a lot of the toolchain was discontinued a while back; my rough memory is that good supports stops around Python 3.6 (and the author of the relevant tools has made it clear that the price tag he's putting on resuming the project goes up the more begging-style support questions he gets from people who aren't technically competent and willing to help).

Comment: what do you mean by "compyled", sorry, did you mean "compiled"?